ACM/AWS not validating certificate for a subdomain
I have my domain managed by Godaddy which I want to point to AWS/EC2. My domain name validates fine. I have a wildcard subdomain definition that is also says it is successfully validated but when I test it using dig +short it is not going through. I then created another certificate for a specific subdomain that shows 'Pending Validation'.
Here is with an example:
First certificate that I created with the two following domains:
abc.com
*.abc.com
Added the CNAME in Godaddy and it validated successfully from ACM. I am able to validate it using dig +short. But I am not able to validate with a subdomain say, blog.abc.com
Then I created blog.abc.com and added it to the Cname on Godaddy. It stays on pending validation.
What should I do to point blog.abc.com to the ip address of EC2?
Note: I have not setup a Route 53 or a load balancer at this time. I am not sure if that is a requirement here.

I had this issue very recently, and the issue was that the CNAME value was ending with a period. I deleted the record and added a new record without '.' at the end in the record and it validated. Can you please check if that is the case with you?

I did that and thats how i got it working for the first example. For the second, blog.abc.com, removing the period didnt help,

"when I test it using dig +short it is not going through" you need to show us exactly what you're doing and exactly how it's failing.  Clearly the subdomain CNAME is not being resolved by ACM, but without specific information, and with only made up generic domain names, we can't help you troubleshoot.

"Note: I have not setup a Route 53 or a load balancer at this time. I am not sure if that is a requirement here."  They are not.  The only requirement is that ACM can look up the CNAME(s) used to validate domain ownership.  Once you can lookup the subdomain CNAME it's asking you to add, then ACM should validate shortly thereafter.

thanks @erik258 for the response. My domain name is rhwb.org. The first certificate has wildcard subdomain setup. dig +short rhwb.org and dig +short www.rhwb.org returns an ip address, whereas dig +short blog.rhwb.org returns empty.
I have another certificate set up for analytics.rhwb.org and also added the CNAME in the DNS entry. This one is showing 'pending validation' in ACM. This is the subdomain i want to make it work.

they all get served by the same godaddy nameservers, so you should be able to add all the cnames there.
